# How can my NDK app download data in the background on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-background

I have an NDK app (game) that needs to download 1gb of game data the first time it's run. It does this in C++ code via TCP/IP. How do I keep the download going if/when the user switches apps?

Comment: Just making sure you are aware of: [Google Play Asset delivery](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-native)

Comment: Yes I am, thanks. In this case we have cross-platform C++ code doing the patching/updating outside of the play store on its own schedule.

Comment: Modern Android saves battery usage via [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby) which shuts down any background network process. This in addition to [non-standard OEM battery saving features](https://dontkillmyapp.com/) also means that the safest/most reliable way to download is to be the foreground active app. Also Google Play Asset delivery does [ask the user if the data connection switches to mobile](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery/integrate-native#large-downloads)